# Showing $f(x)\equiv 0 \ (\text{mod} \ p)$ has a solution in $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $f(x) = (x^{2}-2) \cdot (x^{2}-3) \cdot (x^{2}-6)$. For every prime number $p$ how can I show that $f(x) \equiv 0 \ (\text{mod} \ p)$ has a solution in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match MSE quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. Making these improvements will attract more appropriate answers and make the question more valuable for future MSE visitors.

Answer (score 4):

If prime $p>2,$

$x^2-2\equiv0\pmod p$ will have a solution 
if $x^2\equiv2\pmod p\iff  \left(\frac2p\right)=1$ using [Legendre symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol#Properties_of_the_Legendre_symbol)

Similarly, for $x^2-3, x^2-6$

$$\text{Now, }\left(\frac6p\right)=\left(\frac3p\right)\cdot\left(\frac2p\right)$$

If $\left(\frac3p\right)=\left(\frac2p\right)=-1, \left(\frac6p\right)=1$